# Create a Dynamic Table in your Map Layout

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, dynamic-tables

I am trying to create a graphic table in the layout below are ESRI instruction but I don't have an option to insert the Graphic Table Element (see attached photo

You can only add this table in layout view.

```
Start ArcMap.
On the main menu, click View > Layout View.
On the main menu, click Insert > Graphic Table Element.

The New Table dialog box appears.
Select Interactive format
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Graphic Table Element](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/a-quick-tour-of-the-graphic-table-element-tool.htm) requires `Production Mapping` extension which is an additional  license to run `Production Mapping`. If you do not have the extension, then you cannot use Graphic Table Element. However, if you have the extension, then you may need to enable the extension from `Customize -> Extension` menu.